# Grabbing the last 10 objects from a NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am currently working on a project where I woud, parse the JSON and store a JSON Object into an array.

I do something like this:

```
NSArray *value = [JSONObject valueForKey:@"value"];
```

I have all my values in the array value.

How would I, collect the last 10 values from this array and store it in a second array?

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: what is JSONObjetct? did u parse the json? did you make sure it gave you an array and not a dictionary?

Comment: @vikingosegundo I got this question answered. And yes it gives me a array and not dictionary.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at this method. (Here is a link to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/subarrayWithRange:).)

```
- (NSArray *)subarrayWithRange:(NSRange)range;
```

So in your case it would be:

```
NSArray *value = [JSONObject valueForKey:@"value"];
NSRange endRange = NSMakeRange(value.count >= 10 ? value.count - 10 : 0, MIN(value.count, 10));
NSArray *lastTenObjects= [value subarrayWithRange:endRange];
```

Comment: I would like to know from who down voted what's wrong with this answer, so I can improve it.

Comment: Note that this only works if the array is guaranteed to be 10 or larger, if it is not, I'm not sure what will happen, possibly a crash.

Comment: @JoelFischer I changed the code to not crash with an array that has less than 10 elements.

Comment: actually the type of endRange should be NSRange instead of NSMakeRange. I tried to improve your answer but it wont let me post the edit since it's less than 6 characters.. :(

Comment: fixed the issue you had with answer there @nstefan